# Domain Controller (Windows 8) - cannot grant access to a folder for domain user

Tags: network-share

I have a network that has two domain controllers. One in South Carolina and one in Oklahoma. I have a folder on the Ok DC that is only shared by a few users. I added full control to a user in SC to the folder in OK. When I try to map a drive on the SC users Windows 7 computer, it creates the drive but says the user does not have permission to open it. I already have a SC user that accesses the folder. I'm missing something simple here.

Comment: Have you checked share permissions and NTFS permissions?

Comment: I'm not sure what "share permissions" is.  If I check the properties/security tab on the folder in question,  I see the user has full control.

Comment: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754178.aspx

Comment: Sorry,  I was thinking about something else.

Comment: There are only two sets of permissions for Windows file shares: "Share" permissions and "Security" permissions. When a security principle (user or group) is granted permissions on both (which is required for a user to access a share) it follows the least permissive model. So, if you have "Full Control" security permissions and "Read" share permissions, the effective permission is "read". Please verify that both the share and security permission for the user is set correctly. You might consider removing all other permissions on the share and explicitly adding just the user.

Comment: I missed the share permission.  I was thinking that the NTFS permission should do the trick.  Apparently not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have set the Share permissions and the NTFS permissions